# Realtime Recording angular

Tags: angular, typescript, recordrtc

I use recordRTC to record videos and its working fine.

Since we are building a robot, means the user interacts with the application via (a webcam and a microphone) , example when he says ' i want to buy a ticket ' we analyse his voice in our back-end application(java) then we redirect him to the ' page of tickets purchase '.

here is my code :

```
 mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{    
            let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
             chunks = [];
             let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            vidSave.src = videoURL;  
             var file = new File([blob], 'video.mp4', {
                type: 'video/mp4'
             });        
            //send it to back-end via post //
            let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", blob);   
            req.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8081/avi/upload-file');
             req.send(formData);
              //
         }
```

Every second i send the video so that i am able to analyse it and interact with him while he speaks.
So how can i frame the video (its like a streaming ) ?

I tried to add  this:

```
const duration = 2000;

     setInterval(() => {
     mediaRecorder.requestData()
     }, duration);
```

but it is sending empty videos to my java application.

(sorry for my bad explanation)